# Problema con Fullcalendar

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

Hola Tengo una duda y necesito una ayuda..

tengo esta funcion en calendario.js

```
function cargaCalendario(json_events){

                      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                          header: {

                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                          },
                          defaultDate: new Date(),
                          editable: true,
                          eventLimit: true,
                          height:500,
                          width:400,
                          events: $.parseJSON(json_events),
                          eventDrop: function(event,delta,revertFunc){
                            //alert(event.title+" - "+ event.id +" - " +event.start.format('DD-MM-YYYY[T]HH:MM:SS'));
                            $("#id").val(event.id);
                            $("#tit").val(event.title);
                            $("#finic").val(event.start.format());
                            var titulo;
                            var Fstart;
                            var Fend;
                            alert($('#id').val()+" "+$('#tit').val()+" "+$('#finic').val())
                            var eventid;
                            var id=event.id;
                            var title=event.title;
                            var start=event.start.format();
                            var end=(event.end == null) ? start : event.end.format();

                            //alert(id+" "+title+" "+start+" "+end);                                
                            $.ajax({
                                    url:'leerCalendario.php?op=Actualizar',
                                    type:'get',
                                    data: "titulo="+title+"Fstart="+start+"Fend="+end+"eventid="+id,
                                    async:false,
                                    success: function(response){
                                        if(response.status != 'success')
                                            alert(response.status);
                                        revertFunc();
                                      },
                                      error: function(e){
                                        revertFunc();
                                        alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
                                      }
                                });
                          }
                        });
}
```

. el cual al mover el evendo deveria ejecutar el archivo leerCalendario.php opcion actualiza.

```
case 'Cargar':
        $events = array();
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT idcalendario,paciente,inicio,final FROM calendario");
        while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
         $e=array();
         $e['id']=$fetch['idcalendario'];
         $e['title']=$fetch['paciente'];
         $e['start']=$fetch['inicio'];
         $e['end']=$fetch['final'];
         $e['title']=$fetch['paciente'];
         array_push($events, $e);
        }
        echo json_encode($events);

break;

case 'Actualizar':
        $title=$_POST["titulo"];
        $startdate = $_POST["Fstart"];
        $enddate=$_POST["Fend"];
        $eventid = $_POST["eventid"];   

        $actualiza = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE calendario SET paciente='$title', inicio = '$startdate', final = '$enddate' WHERE idcalendario='$eventid'");
        if($actualiza)
          echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success'));
        else
          echo json_encode(array('status'=>'failed'));
break;
```

Pero no me ejecuta la variable $actualiza la cual hace un update. me devuelve en response.status "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

No estás armando correctamente los datos para enviar por GET:

> data: "titulo="+title+"Fstart="+start+"Fend="+end+"eventid="+id

Cada parámetro (variable) debe estar separado por **&**

```
data: "titulo="+title+"&Fstart="+start+"&Fend="+end+"&eventid="+id
```